# Bootstrap 4 table column width

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

`.col-*-*` classes in the `th` tags do not work anymore in latest 4.x version. Does anyone know how can I resize table columns?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="col-sm-3">3 columns wide</th>
      <th class="col-sm-4">4 columns wide</th>
      <th class="col-sm-5">5 columns wide</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Recommend removing the `twitter-bootstrap` tag as it refers to earlier versions of Bootstrap

Comment: try adding class="row" to the tr. It worked for me